# Convert PI to base 4. Does my unique human genome exist in the sequence of digits?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

The human genome consists of sequences of BASE Pairs A G C T
Convert the number PI to base 4. Does my unique human genome exist in the sequence of digits?

Comment: Yes, if $\pi$ is a normal number. That's probable but not known.

Comment: @EthanBolker  -- Presumably you are using the word "normal" in some technical sense, not in the usual English sense?

Comment: Do you know your unique human genome sequence?

Comment: It's possible but there is no guarantee unless you find it.

Comment: "Normal" in mathematical sense means a number whose decimal expansion (in any base) will have normal distribution of digits.  If so every string will *eventually* appear.  We don't know if pi is normal but it probably is.

Comment: Related : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem

Comment: Rational numbers are not normal the digits are periodic or finite for all but 0 or 9.  A number whose decimal expansion contains only 5s and 9s is not normal.  No number in the cantor set is normal.  The number .1212312341234512345612345678123456789123456789101234567891011... is not normal. Etc.  Surprisingly proving a number *is* normal is ... practically impossible.

Comment: @fleablood: Your example number may not be normal, but it does contain user316076's genome.

Comment: Wha... oh. Yes, yes it does.  Doesn't it?  And unlike pi we know where, don't we?  I wasn't really thinking about that.  The number (base 10) .101001000100001... is not normal and probably doesn't contain the op's DNA either unless the op's DNA is very unnormallike.

Comment: You can search for five digit (base 10) strings in $\pi$ here and at other places on the net: http://www.facade.com/legacy/amiinpi/

Answer (score 1):

A heuristic argument would go as follows: Assume your genome $G$ is a string of $n\gg1$ digits over $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Denote by $x_k$ the $k^{\rm th}$ digit of $\pi$ in base $4$. For each $r\geq0$ the probability  that
$$(x_{rn+1},x_{rn+2},\ldots,x_{rn+n-1}, x_{(r+1)n})\ne G$$
amounts to $(4^n-1)/ 4^n<1$. Therefore the probability that for no $r\geq0$ we have  a coincidence is
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left({4^n-1\over 4^n}\right)^N=0\ .$$

Comment: This assumes that pi has a normal distribution of decimal digits in base 4, does it not? So this probability is only correct if pi is a normal number (still an open problem).

Comment: @MarkB: Of course. This has been addressed in the comments to the question. But I'm not so confident about the OP's sophistication. Maybe you have overseen the word "heuristic" in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The facts are these:

- nobody knows the answer for sure;
- every mathematician in the world expects that the answer is Yes.

But we don't have a proof one way or the other, in spite of much effort invested in the problem.